# how to change topmenu and fill with my own categories and sub categories?

Tags: magento2, topmenu

I wanted to remove all menu items from top menu and fill in with my categories and subcategories and make it point to different pages that I create. should I edit `topmenu.phtml` file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new module that disables the plugin that adds the categories to the top menu and create a new plugin that adds your custom links to it.
Let's call the module `StackExchange_Menu`.

you will need the following files:

`app/code/StackExchange/Menu/registration.php` - the registration file

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_Topmenu',
    __DIR__
);
```

`app/code/StackExchange/Menu/etc/module.xml` - the module declaration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_Menu" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`app/code/StackExchange/Menu/etc/di.xml` - the module di file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="catalogTopmenu" disabled="true" /> <!-- disable the plugin that adds the categories -->
        <plugin name="stackexchange-menu" type="StackExchange\Menu\Plugin\Menu" /> <!-- declare your own plugin -->
    </type>
</config>
```

`app/code/StackExchange/Menu/Plugin/Menu.php` - the actual plugin where you can add your menu items.

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Menu\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;

class Menu
{
    /**
     * @var NodeFactory
     */
    protected $nodeFactory;

    public function __construct(
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory
    ) {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
    }

    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {
        $menu = $subject->getMenu();
        //here is how you can create a menu item.  
        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => [
                    'name' => __('Label goes here'),
                    'id' => 'some-unique-id-here',
                    'url' => 'http://www.example.com/',
                    'has_active' => false,
                    'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
                ],
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $menu->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $menu->addChild($node); 

        //do the above as many times as you need.  
        //if you want to add a sumbmenu item to a menu item, create a node called `$subNode` in the same way as above and instead of calling $menu->addChild($node); call $node->addChild($subNode);  where $node is the parnet node
    }
}
```

When you are done, run in console `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.
Note: The code above is not tested. Watch out for syntax error.